# iframe with javascript framekiller function

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have been reading about frame killer function, is there a way to show the iframe content only in a specific webpage? I have not tried any thing yet

Comment: Google? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller

Answer (score 0):

If web site A places web site B in an iframe, a couple of interesting things happen.

At the server for B, when B is requested, A shows up in the referer field.  This suggests that the web server could be programmed to reject the requests or redirect them.

The other thing is, on web page B in a javascript, top !== self.  Upon detecting this situation the page could pop up an alert box, navigate away, or do other interesting things.

So while what you are wanting is straightforward, the flaws are the kinds of countermeasures mentioned on wikipedia, and the ability of server-side tools to forge referer headers and request the content like a valid browser would and then reserve it.